# Interpolating rasters into mosaic from point data using LayerTime object in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, error-000840

While trying to run the ArcGIS provided python script to interpolate a bunch of rasters on a time-enabled point feature class file I get the following error:

> Runtime error  Traceback (most recent call last):   File "",
>   line 34, in    File "c:\program files
>   (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.2\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 6043, in
>   MakeFeatureLayer     raise e ExecuteError: ERROR 000840: The value is
>   not a Feature Layer.

My code is this (line 34 is talking about making a feature class, and I cannot for the life of me figure out what it's referring to):

```
    import arcpy, datetime
# Check out the ArcGIS Spatial Analyst extension for using the IDW interpolation tool
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("spatial")

arcpy.env.workspace = "C:\Users\Chris\Desktop\interpolation\Interpolation.gdb"

# Get the layer time properties
lyr = arcpy.mapping.Layer(r"C:\Users\Chris\Desktop\interpolation\points.lyr")
lyrTime = lyr.time

# Calculate the number of iterations based on the time extent and timestep interval
startTime = lyrTime.startTime
endTime = lyrTime.endTime
timeExtent = endTime - startTime
timeStepInterval = lyrTime.timeStepInterval

iterations = timeExtent.days / timeStepInterval.interval

# Get the time field containing the time values associated
# with the data in the time-enabled layer
startTimeField = str(lyrTime.startTimeField)

# Specify the output mosaic dataset to which the interpolated rasters will be added 
outputMosaicDataset = r"C:\Users\Chris\Desktop\interpolation\Interpolation.gdb\rasta"

i = 0
while i <= iterations:
    # Formulate the time query and increment the time by the timeStepInterval
    currentTime = str(startTime + (i*timeStepInterval))
    timeQuery = "\"" + startTimeField + "\"" + " = date '" + currentTime + "'"

    # Create an in-memory feature layer containing points that are valid at each timestep
    tempFeatureLyr = "tempTimeLayer" + str(i)
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(lyr, tempFeatureLyr, timeQuery)

    # Create an interpolated raster surface using the points valid at each timestep
    outRaster = r"C:\Users\Chris\Desktop\interpolation\Interpolation.gdb\output" + str(i)
    print outRaster
    arcpy.gp.Idw_sa(tempFeatureLyr, "avg_hrly", outRaster)

    # Add the newly created raster surface to a Mosaic Dataset
    arcpy.AddRastersToMosaicDataset_management(outputMosaicDataset, "Raster Dataset", outRaster)

    i = i + 1

# Calculate the statistics on the output Mosaic Dataset for
# classifying your data after new rasters are added   
arcpy.CalculateStatistics_management(outputMosaicDataset,"1","1","#")
```

The error (near top of this post) points to line 34, which reads:

```
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(lyr, tempFeatureLyr, timeQuery)
```

I have checked lyr.isFeatureLayer and it's `True`, timeQuery returns the next time slice in a proper string format that i have verified in the SQL builder, and tempFeatureLyr = `'tempTimeLayer1'`...but it does not create it. As in, I do not see tempTimeLayer1 layer in the Table of Contents, though `tempTimeLayer0` IS. So, it's not being created, though its name (tempTimeLayer1) is ready to go...

Here is the site I got the help from, example 3:
[LayerTime(arcpy.mapping)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s300000063000000)

Comment: Your code does not show your `lyr` variable being set anywhere.

Comment: I'm confused - there's no error showing in the "python window comments while the tool is running" that you posted.  I would try running your code from IDLE and then posting the exact error it throws against the exact code you post.

Comment: i have, it's at the very top. The rest was posted not knowing if it would help others or not; evidently, I'll just remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are showing is coming from `c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.2\arcpy\arcpy\management.py` and it would be easier to take a stab at its cause if we knew the precise line from your script - running it in IDLE is how I usually find that.

It may be that it is simply due to you having:

```
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:\Users\Chris\Desktop\interpolation\Interpolation.gdb"
```

instead of:

```
arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\Users\Chris\Desktop\interpolation\Interpolation.gdb"
```

Comment: thanks for the thought, i'll put the r in and let you know. In reference to taking a stab at the arcpy\management.py error, I actually opened up the file and had intentions of going to line 6043 to get more info, but the code is obfuscated, or something, and I couldn't see more than the first 30 lines or so. Standby and I will adjust with the r. What does the r and u do before paths anyway?

Comment: I would advise strongly against editing anything in `c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.2\arcpy\arcpy` because it could invalidate your install. `r` stands for raw and says to just read the rest of the string "as-is" without interpreting the backslashes as escape characters. `u` is to do with Unicode characters.

Comment: noted, thanks. I was more or less wanting to poke around the see where it tripped. I appreciate the explanation on r/u, cheers.

Comment: The errors from IDLE usually point me straight at where the problem lies.

Comment: So in going to IDLE to see what line or info might help it actually ran! Thanks for the nudge